# Azure custom domain name

Tags: azure, dns, azure-web-app-service, hostname

when I create a new custom domain for a site on Azure, does it check if the name is already been used.
The host name is in the form ***myhostName*.azurewebsites.net**.
Does Azure check if the *myhostName* name has been already used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can't create website with name which has already been taken, you will see this: 
[image]